# How do I use a vue font awesome component in a data variable?

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome-5

Trying to pass this subheading to a child component using a prop, but I'm not sure how to get around it taking the font awesome icon component as a string...

Parent

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      subheading: "<font-awesome-icon icon="fire"/> Hot Item"
    }
  }
}
```

Child

```
...
<span>{{ subheading }}</span>
...
```

**Output**
`<span><font-awesome-icon icon="fire"/> Hot Item</span>`

**Desired Output**
`<span><svg...> Hot Item</span>`

Answer (score 0):

```
import { dom } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'

dom.watch()
```

Then just simple `<i>` with `fas` class.

source: https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome

Comment: whilst it might work for `<i>` elements directly placed on the dom, it wouldn't work with the OP's example as the html in `{{ subheading }}` would be escaped.

Comment: for me it;s working. used variable to render i element